# How do I remove gapps from CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-apps

I installed CyanogenMod 11 on my HTC One with CyanogenMod Installer. So I got also the google Apps (gapps) on my device. But I need a CM11 without gapps.
I did then the following without success:

1. copy cm-11-20140308-SNAPSHOT-M4-m7.zip to /sdcard/
2. boot to recovery mode -> recovery -> ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.6:
3. "wipe data/factory reset"
4. "install zip" choosing the zip-file
5. "reboot system now"

   So I got a new CM11 but with gapps still installed.

   What should I do in addition to "wipe data/factory reset" to get rid of this apps?

Comment: Formatting the system partition before re-installing would probably do it. I think CM is automatically backing up and restoring Gapps, the idea being that it makes updates easier for people who use Gapps. Since they get installed to the system partition, the factory reset won't delete them.

Answer (score 22):

The solution for my my problem was:

- Wipe data/factory reset AND
- Clear cache and Dalvik cache AND
- Format system partition

This can be done using ClockworkMod using various menus.

Comment: Set as solution. Maybe you want to add the software you used for these steps.

Comment: There is no additional software involved, other than booting into Recovery.

Comment: I also had to install CM again after these steps, but maybe because I said "No" to rooting the phone again on a reboot, and perhaps CM does that anyway (yes this is not the most intellectual comment)

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you *can* remove it without a reinstall

1. `adb shell`
2. `su`
3. `mount -o rw,remount /system`
4. `rm -R /system/addon.d`

Source here : [How to fix wrong Google apps](https://github.com/M66B/cm-xtended/wiki/How-to-fix-wrong-Google-apps)

Comment: This only remove the gapp autoload scripts. Then reboot and you can uninstall them.

Comment: Doesn't it say that after you did this you had to reboot and flash ROM again? Not sure if that doesn't count as a reinstall...

Comment: @atrioom it skips wiping or formatting the system partition, so you're not quite starting from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but it shows up pretty high on Google and is the only relevant one to my own quest when I was trying to remove Gapps/Google Apps from my phone, so I figured I'd add my two cents.

The above answers **did not work for me**. What I did was the following:

(*WARNING: this may brick some devices!*)

- Forcibly flash a bogus image using a low level flash tool (e.g Androxyde FlashTool) into the phone's system ROM, e.g 10mb worth zeroes should do the trick to overwrite the file allocation table.
- Install recovery if it has been removed by the above operation. You can do this by holding the phone specific button combo to put it in flash mode (e.g power and volume-down), and then flashing the boot.img file that's included in most rom files using the flash tool you used in the previous step.
- Boot into recovery, and install your rom of choice.

This will create a completely *clean* system ROM with *only* the applications included in the ROM itself. 
If you decide that you want Google apps later after all, just search for 'GApps android' or go to http://opengapps.org .

Answer (score -2):

Wipe your cache partition and wipe your dalvik cache and reinstall.

Comment: I'm guessing this is missing the step "Format system partition" and that's why it got the downvote.